# Where can I get the missing figures from the freely available, classic "Programming Ruby" e-book?

Tags: ruby

I am studying the content of "Programming Ruby- The Pragmatic Programmer's Guide" but the HTML version does not include the Figures.

Are the figures available anywhere online?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the HTML version applies to an older version of Ruby and is no longer maintained.  If you want to learn Ruby via the *Programming Ruby* book, you should buy [the latest edition](http://pragprog.com/titles/ruby/programming-ruby).

Comment: I was afraid someone would say this.

Comment: Surely someone out there has a copy of the figures posted on some website...

Comment: Fine... !   you win.   I'll go buy the new book.  :(